# ¿Como usar espacios en lugar de tabs en vim?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

Programo en python con VIM 8, y tengo esta duda, lei que en PEP8 se recomienda que las identaciones para python deben de ser de 4 ESPACIOS, en mi .vimrc tengo configurado esto por una recomendacion de un video de Youtube:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
```

¿Es correcta esta configuracion para que cada que presiona la tecla TAB se hagan los 4 espacios automaticamente?

he visto otras configuraciones como, tabstop, smarttab y otras pero no me queda muy claro cual debo usaar para micaso.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Mi .vimrc en github: https://github.com/SetCain/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 1):

Veamos:

- `shiftwidth`: Es para determinar los espacios de identación en el caso del código, si vas a usar también el `tab` para establecer la identación. Recuerda además, que de forma general (no necesariamente para código), tienes la configuración `tabstop` para determinar la longitud del `tab`.
- `expandtab`: Esta configuración es la que le indica a **Vim** que "expanda" cada `tab` en espacios.
- `softtabstop`: Tiene sentido si no expandes los tabs a espacios con `set noexpandtab` (no es tu caso) y si además el valor de esta configuración difiere del de `tabstop`. Hace que sea **Vim** quién decida como combinar espacios y tabs para llegar a la cifra de softtabstop`.
- `autoindent`: Simplemente te mantendrá la identación actual en la siguiente línea que escribas

Para lo que buscas en realidad solo haría falta:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
```

Answer (score 1):

encontre otra pregunta similar a la tuya en la version en Ingles.

aqui la respuesta mas votada

agrega esto en tu .vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
```

mas info en:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234564/tab-key-4-spaces-and-auto-indent-after-curly-braces-in-vim

Suerte, R6